# What is wrong with my if statement in this multiplication test generator?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

This is a multiplication test generator. When I enter the correct answer, it still displays the message "No. Please try again."

```
import random

answer = 0

def generate_numbers():
    num1 = random.randrange(0,10)
    num2 = random.randrange(0,10)
    return(num1, num2)

def display_question(answer):
    num1, num2 = numbers
    answer = num1 * num2
    guess = int(input(f'What is {num1} times {num2}?'))
                
    while guess != answer:
        print("No. Please try again")
        display_question()

    print("Very good!")
```

Comment: What is purpose of `answer` argument in display_question ?

Comment: You are recursing again into `display_question` (as written). Either use a loop or take the while loop outside of `display_question`.

Comment: What is `numbers`? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Also please tell us the exact output you get, and the exact input you give.

Comment: And please take some time to take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are using `answer` as argument but this should work :-

```py
import random

def generate_numbers():
    num1 = random.randrange(0,10)
    num2 = random.randrange(0,10)
    return(num1, num2)

def display_question():
    num1, num2 = generate_numbers()
    answer = num1 * num2
    guess = int(input(f'What is {num1} times {num2} ?\n'))
                
    if guess != answer:
        print("No. Please try again\n")
        display_question()
    else:
        print("Very good!")

display_question()
```